# reduce size of zinc dust

Tags: metal, colloids

I am working with zinc dust (particles of 10um). I want to make a stable dispersion of this dust with arabic gum. The problem is that the particles are still too big, the solution rapidly settles.... My idea to decrease particles size was to use HCl to corrode Zn into Zn2+. And then stopping the reaction by adding soda. I thought getting something light but instead I have a precipitate less soluble than my first zn solution. What happens ? What would be the best strategy to decrease zn particles size ?

Comment: I might suggest ball milling, rather than a chemical route.